# Opendistro Kibana REST API returns 404

Tags: rest, elasticsearch-opendistro

I am playing with Opendistro Elastic + Kibana. I have followed this guide to run these services locally via docker compose: [docker-compose.yml](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/install/docker/#sample-docker-compose-file). All starts fine and after pushing some data to elastic, I am able to see it via Kibana.

Elasticsearch REST API works fine. However any attempt to access Kibana REST API fails with 404:

```
> curl -X GET -u admin:admin 'http://localhost:5601/api/features'
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
```

My understanding was that Opendistro is a fork of an original ELK (before recent license changes). I was therefore expecting that features present in Kibana prior to 7.11 would be present in Opendistro.

Does Opendistro Kibana expose any REST API?
Is there any functionality in Opendistro similar to this one [spaces-api-copy-saved-objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.10/spaces-api-copy-saved-objects.html#spaces-api-copy-saved-objects)?
I am looking into a way to manage spaces/ tenants via REST API.

Answer (score 0):

After further research it seems that all the functionalities marked as X-Pack are not present in Opendistro Kibana. This is a proprietary code and therefore could not be forked. Therefore [Space API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.10/spaces-api.html) is not present in Opendistro Kibana, while [Saved objects API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.10/saved-objects-api.html) works just fine.

Some of the functionalities licensed under X-Pack has been rewritten in the form of Opendistro plugins and are exposed via REST API by Elasticsearch, not Kibana (e.g. reporting).

Answer (score 0):

All Opendistro (OpenSearch now) are plugins and only compatible with OSS version of Elasticsearch or Kibana. so the features are the first column [here](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) + Opendistro plugins